# How to stop fscanf when user presses Enter if < max args are typed

Tags: c, scanf

I have 3 char arrays declared this way:

```
char arg1[25];
char arg2[25];
char arg3[25];
```

I prompt the user to enter some arguments this way:

```
fscanf(stdin, "%s %s %s", arg1, arg2, arg3);

printf(" %s %s %s", arg1, arg2, arg3);
```

My issue is that the user might only enter values for arg1 and arg2 then press Enter.

How can i use fscanf so that the user does not need to enter all 3 arguments before pressing Enter?

The values in these arrays are to be used with execvp.

Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

`fgets` will accept input up to Enter. `sscanf` can then parse the input into whitespace separated strings and return the number of strings scanned.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){
    char input[100] = "";
    char arg1[25] = "";
    char arg2[25] = "";
    char arg3[25] = "";
    int scanned = 0;

    fgets ( input, sizeof input, stdin);
    scanned = sscanf ( input, "%24s%24s%24s", arg1, arg2, arg3);
    if ( scanned == 1) {
        printf ( "%s\n", arg1);
    }
    if ( scanned == 2) {
        printf ( "%s %s\n", arg1, arg2);
    }
    if ( scanned == 3) {
        printf ( "%s %s %s\n", arg1, arg2, arg3);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: what type is your variable 'line' ?